# Correct database type for mysql to store values: 0.0 to 1.0

Tags: mysql, database

I am adding the priority field to XML sitemap to the database and was wondering what is the correct database type to store values range from 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: What amount of decimal precision do you want to achieve?

Comment: Only 1 decimal place to store the priority: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#prioritydef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DECIMAL(2, 1)`, although that will actually be capable of storing `-9.9` to `9.9`.

Comment: Ideally I want MYSQL to always ensure that the number entered is between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: @John Magnolia The easiest way of enforcing that is using triggers.